# How to open a WebView in another Activity by pressing a button?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, webview

I made a program in which i am making a button in main activity and then on clicking it, a new activity which will give me a webview.
Here's my code for mainactivity.java

```
public class ButtonWebActivity extends Activity {


@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);      


Button z=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

z.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),WebLinks.class);
            startActivity(intent);

    }
});
}
}
```

And here is my second activity.java code:

```
     public class WebLinks extends Activity {
 @Override

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.weblinks);

    WebView wv=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview1);

     WebSettings ws=wv.getSettings();
        ws.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
        wv.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

    }
private class Callback extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        return(false);
    }
}
   }
```

Here is my LogCat-

```
 07-06 09:22:50.626: D/AndroidRuntime(271): Shutting down VM
 07-06 09:22:50.626: W/dalvikvm(271): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught   exception (group=0x4001d800)
 07-06 09:22:50.656: E/AndroidRuntime(271): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 07-06 09:22:50.656: E/AndroidRuntime(271): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
 07-06 09:22:50.656: E/AndroidRuntime(271):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
 07-06 09:22:50.656: E/AndroidRuntime(271):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
 07-06 09:22:50.656: E/AndroidRuntime(271):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
 07-06 09:22:50.656: E/AndroidRuntime(271):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
 07-06 09:22:50.656: E/AndroidRuntime(271):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 07-06 09:22:50.656: E/AndroidRuntime(271):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 07-06 09:22:50.656: E/AndroidRuntime(271):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
 07-06 09:22:50.656: E/AndroidRuntime(271):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 07-06 09:22:50.656: E/AndroidRuntime(271):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 07-06 09:22:50.656: E/AndroidRuntime(271):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
 07-06 09:22:50.656: E/AndroidRuntime(271):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
 07-06 09:22:50.656: E/AndroidRuntime(271):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 07-06 09:22:50.656: E/AndroidRuntime(271): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 07-06 09:22:50.656: E/AndroidRuntime(271):     at web.on.buttons.ButtonWebActivity.onClick(ButtonWebActivity.java:32)
 07-06 09:22:50.656: E/AndroidRuntime(271):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 07-06 09:22:50.656: E/AndroidRuntime(271):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 07-06 09:22:50.656: E/AndroidRuntime(271):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
 07-06 09:22:50.656: E/AndroidRuntime(271):     ... 11 more
 07-06 09:22:50.656: E/AndroidRuntime(271): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {web.on.buttons/net.open.sports.WebLinks}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
 07-06 09:22:50.656: E/AndroidRuntime(271):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1404)
 07-06 09:22:50.656: E/AndroidRuntime(271):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
 07-06 09:22:50.656: E/AndroidRuntime(271):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
 07-06 09:22:50.656: E/AndroidRuntime(271):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
 07-06 09:22:50.656: E/AndroidRuntime(271):     ... 15 more
```

When i press on the button in the app, Dialog box comes that "web.on.buttons has stopped unexpectedly.Please try again later."
Can anyone tell me Where i went wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: post the stacktrace. Also use activity context  `Intent intent = new Intent(ButtonWebActivity.this,WebLinks.class)`

Comment: @Raghunandan I tried to open LogCat View, now eclipse is not responding?

Answer (score 0):

try this please

```
z.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(ButtonWebActivity.this, WebLinks.class)); 

        }
   });
```

Comment: Tried this too, bt no success

Answer (score 0):

Change your code from

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),WebLinks.class);
     startActivity(intent);
 }
```

To this :

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ButtonWebActivity.this,WebLinks.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Always use your Activity's context when calling intents.

Comment: Can you put up the Stack trace here. One more thing have you registered the activities on the Manifest.xml

Comment: Yes, i have registered activities in manifest.xml file. I have written logcat in the question(updated).

Comment: I found out the mistake. Thanks for your time. It was a silly mistake